# How to capture child links clicked using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, click

I am trying to capture the event when a child element link is clicked and add class called "highlightchild" to it. Also I want to check if there are any child element link exist or not, if no child element exits ie  "third level" highlight with "highlightparent" the parent. How can I do that using jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu ul').hide();
  $('.menu .arrowUp').click(function() {
  $('.menu ul').hide();
  $(this).find(".third-level").toggle();
  });
});
```

*html*

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link1</a>
 <ul class="third-level" >             
 <!-- third level non-active -->
  <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/somelink/">Some Link</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link2</a>
 <ul class="third-level" >             
 <!-- third level non-active -->
  <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/links2/">some Links 2</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link3</a>
 <ul class="third-level" >
 <!-- third level non-active -->
     <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/Agri/">Agricultural</a></li>
     <!-- third level non-active -->
      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/sugar/">Sugar</a></li>
    <!-- third level non-active -->
      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/bbc/">Coffee</a></li>
      <!-- third level non-active -->
      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/cnn/">Energy</a></li>
      <!-- third level non-active -->
      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="funstuff">Fun stuff</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link4</a></li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link5</a></li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you meant with your second part (could rephrase it and/or clarify?), but I would use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('ul.menu').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    $('ul.menu .highlightchild').removeClass('.highlightchild');
    $(this).addClass('.highlightchild');
});
```

This adds only *one* event handler to the root of the menu.

Comment: I think this is the better alternative than adding listeners to all the nodes.  My only suggestion would be that you could do a check for $(this).hasClass(".highlightchild") instead of querying, removing, adding.

Comment: @Newtang: It is for removing the class from the previously clicked element. `$(this).hasClass(".highlightchild")` would only help to see whether the element was the one clicked before. I'm not really sure though what the OP wants to achieve an whether my solution fits. But event delegation is something which should be preferred than adding thousands of events handler.s

Answer (score 0):

```
// add hightlightChild class to children anchor tags on click
$('.parent_link > a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('highlightChild');
  return false; // or not if you want to follow the link
});

// loop over each parent link and highlight it if no children links exist
$('.parent_link').each(function(){
  if ( $(this).children('a').size() > 0 ){
    $(this).addClass('highlightParent');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(".arrowUp > a").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest(".third-level").length > 0 ||
        $(this).siblings().length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

All links with a parent with class `third-level`, or links with no sibling `a`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/bMupR/

**Edit:** Didn't notice you wanted different parent/child highlight classes, here's how you would do that:

```
$(".arrowUp > a").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest(".third-level").length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("childhighlight");
    }
    else if ($(this).siblings().length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass("parenthighlight");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/bMupR/1/